# In Langchain, why ConversationalRetrievalChain not remembering the chat history and Entering new ConversationalRetrievalChain chain for each chat?

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

I am trying to create an customer support system using langchain. I am using text documents as external knowledge provider via TextLoader

In order to remember the chat I using ConversationalRetrievalChain with list of chats

My problem is, each time when I execute `conv_chain({"question": prompt, "chat_history": chat_history})`,

it is creating a new ConversationalRetrievalChain that is, in the log, `I get Entering new ConversationalRetrievalChain chain >`  message

And the chat_history array looks like, multiple nested arrays :

```
[[ "Hi I am Ragesh", "Hi Ragesh, How are your"] , ["What is my name?", "Sorry, As an AI....., " ]]
```

So it couldn't remember my previous chat.

Why this is happening ?

I am very new to AI field. Please help me.

My code:

https://gist.github.com/RageshAntony/79a9050b76e74f5ea868888cd57c6705

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example inline, in your actual post, instead of linking to Github.

Comment: ["By default, Chains and Agents are stateless, meaning that they treat each incoming query independently"](https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/memory.html) - the LangChain docs highlight that Chains are stateless by nature - they do not preserve memory. However there are a number of Memory objects that can be added to conversational chains to preserve state/chat history. Have a look at [this documentation on how to add memory to a ConversatoinalRetrievalChain](https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/chains/index_examples/chat_vector_db.html).

Comment: Chech whether this helps -> [Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76722077/why-doesnt-langchain-conversationalretrievalchain-remember-the-chat-history-ev/77263321#77263321)

Answer (score 2):

you may add something here

```
def generate_response(support_qa: BaseConversationalRetrievalChain, prompt):
    response = support_qa({"question": prompt, "chat_history": chat_history})
    chat_history.append((prompt, response["answer"]))
    print( json.dumps(chat_history))
    return response['answer']
```

to this code below. for the time you need you history

```
def generate_response(support_qa: BaseConversationalRetrievalChain, prompt):
    chat_history = [(prompt, --**previous chat_history** --)]
    response = support_qa({"question": prompt, "chat_history": chat_history})
    chat_history.append((prompt, response["answer"]))
    print( json.dumps(chat_history))
    return response['answer']
```

this will ensure that support_qa chat_history is the history you were looking for. be carefull with token maximum issues. you may need to use map-reduce to summarize your history.

Comment: What if `chatHistory` contains string literals something like `{abc}`

Answer (score 0):

```
support_qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
        llm=llm,
        retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(),
        # retriever=support_store.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 3}),
        verbose=True,
        return_source_documents=True,
        combine_docs_chain_kwargs={"prompt": SUPPORT_PROMPT},
        # qa_prompt=SUPPORT_PROMPT,
        condense_question_prompt=CONDENSE_QUESTION_PROMPT,
    )
```

This can slove the question.

Comment: Can you please post full code. could not understand the difference between support prompt and CONDENSE_QUESTION_PROMPT

Answer (score -3):

You need to update your Langchain version

Comment: how it will resolve the issue>